# Unix shell script to update the date (T) appearing in file with T+2

Tags: shell, unix

There is a file.txt with content as mentioned below

```
user,joiningDate
A,14/Dec/17
B,29/Dec/17
C,30/Nov/17
D,29/Sep/17
E,28/Feb/17
```

I require a unix shell script that could update JoiningDate with JoiningDate+2 and should also ignore weekends. So output should be like as below

```
user,joiningDate
A,18/Dec/17
B,02/Jan/18
C,04/Dec/17
D,03/Oct/17
E,02/Mar/17
```

Comment: Okay. Thanks for the status update. What's your question tho? And where is your code? You should probably read [this](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). Stackoverflow is not a free coding service.

Comment: @NullDev I do not know how can I add 2 days in a date that appearing as a string in file using shell script. this is one of the part of my query, other query is to update the date format, that I already did. But how to update the date string with date+2, that I am not able to code.

Comment: Please [edit](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/48184280/edit) your question rather than adding additional stuff in the comment.

Comment: if you know the answer then please answer it rather adding comment or degrading it

Comment: FWIW crossposted at https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/416021/unix-shell-script-to-update-the-date-t-appearing-in-file-with-t2

Comment: StackOverflow is about helping people fix their existing programming code. Requests for tutorials, research, tools, recommendations, libraries, and **code** are off-topic.  ***Please*** read https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic ,   https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask , https://stackoverflow.com/help/dont-ask ,  https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve  and take the [tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour) before posting more Qs here. Good luck.

Answer (score 0):

Sharing the code with Shell script with-

```
#!/bin/sh

# @Author Jatish.Khanna[@]gmail[.]com

if [ $# -eq 0 ]; then

 echo "Exiting - input file not specified"
 exit
fi

count=0
while IFS='' read -r line || [[ -n "$line" ]]; do

#Skipping header from the input file - user,joiningDate
if [ $count -eq 0 ]; then
   count=$((count + 1))
   continue
 fi

# getting the date
found_date_old=$(echo $line | cut -d, -f2)

# converting into required format
found_date=$(echo  $found_date_old | tr '/' ' ')

# addind number of days to the date
new_date=$(date +%d/%b/%y -d "$found_date 2 day")

record=$(echo $line | sed "s|${found_date_old}|${new_date}|")
echo "$record"

done < "$1"
```

Assumptions for this solution:

a) the input format is expected as

```
[any text],date[,any text]
```

The input date is delimited using "," and expected to be in second column

Note: This can be customized easily by updating section

```
#Getting the date
found_date_old=$(echo $line | cut -d, -f2)
```

b) The input date present in column should be accepted by Linux $(date) command

c) The expected output format can be customized whereas we have loads of options available with date command

Comment: script doesn't handle to ignore weekends.

Comment: @TobySpeight I have added assumption. Hope it would help future readers.